# How to verify a input do not exceed the the maximum length using automation testing?

Tags: java, testing, automation, testng, rest-assured

Here, I tried to verify that my opco_id test data do not exceed the maximum length of three digits. When I run the test script, it failed. I am a newbie to automation testing. Can anyone help me to solve it? you can use any kind of example you prefer to explain it.

Comment: There should be an Assertion on the request. If you expect the API to return 400 Bad Request then you can assert that with Rest-Assured. You can also make assertions on the response of the API

Comment: Could you provide sample  your`opco_id test data`?